# Vue.js Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js

I'm learning to use Vue.js with Laravel from this [series](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gx93Bz62AII) the narrator doesn't get any error but I've encountered the following error while I click to change the route.

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined.

Below code is from my `app.js`:

```js
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

let routes = [{
    path: '/dashboard',
    component: require('./components/Dashboard.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/profile',
    component: require('./components/Profile.vue')
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router
});
```

Code snippet from my `Dashboard.vue`:

```html
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Dashboard Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
  }
</script>
```

Code snippet from my `master.blade.php` layout:

```html
//sidebar
<ul>
  <li>
    <router-link to="/dashboard" class="nav-link">Dashboard</li>
  <li>
    <router-link to="/profile" class="nav-link">Profile</li>
</ul>
//content
<div class="container-fluid">
  <router-view></router-view>
</div>
```

I'm running app at `localhost:3000`with `browserSync` and `npm run watch`. Does it has anything to do with error ?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Try adding `.default` to your component requires:

```js
let routes = [{
    path: '/dashboard',
    component: require('./components/Dashboard.vue').default
  },
  {
    path: '/profile',
    component: require('./components/Profile.vue').default
  }
]
```

Comment: Thanks. It worked. Could you please help me understand what your suggested code just did ?

Comment: no worries! Glad to help :) - you could also do

component: () => import('../components/Test.vue')

aswell I believe :)

Comment: I'm not sure 100% why it doesn't work without it, just that it has something to do with async components - could you mark my answer as correct please :)

Answer (score 2):

While not applicable to the specifics of this question, the error message above can also be encountered when failing to wrap one's HTML in `<template>`...`</template>` tags. This would cause vue to not detect a template, as none has been defined via tags or object properties.

For example, within `Dashboard.vue`, if one were to write (within `Dashboard.vue`):

```
<!-- EXAMPLE OF INCORRECT SYNTAX: missing <template> tag -->
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">Dashboard Component</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    I'm an example component.
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
  }
</script>
```

rather than:

```
<template> <!-- NOTE THE <template> tag, here -->
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Dashboard Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template> <!-- NOTE THE </template> tag, here -->

<script>
  export default {
    mounted() {
      console.log('Component mounted.')
    }
  }
</script>
```

one would receive the error message: `Vue.js Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined`

Answer (score 0):

// Just add "import Vue from 'vue'" and the component will be shown !

```js
require('./bootstrap');


window.Vue = require('vue');

import VueRouter from 'vue-router'
Vue.use(VueRouter)

let routes = [{
    path: '/dashboard',
    component: require('./components/Dashboard.vue')
  },
  {
    path: '/profile',
    component: require('./components/Profile.vue')
  }
]

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes
})

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  router
});
```

Answer (score 0):

This was bugging me for so long, the change is so small that I could barely notice it in two different router files, among which one works, one doesn't.

Instead of

```
let routes = [{
    path: '/dashboard',
    component: require('./components/Dashboard.vue')
  }]
```

you should use

```
let routes = [{
        path: '/dashboard',
        component:()=> import('./components/Dashboard.vue')
      }]
```

The point is component property will also accept a function, and in that function, you can return an imported component which will only be called when it is required. If you give `require()` directly, it is imported immediately.